# Google Analytics causing 500 internal error

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-analytics

Using this code generated from googles analytic product: (information censored)

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />



<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 
    'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 
    'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Causes internal 500 error, the code is in the head tag

Comment: it can't be from google analytics , check the error log to get more detailed error

Comment: you should put it at bottom of the page ! Something else might be causing this

Comment: @Muhammet not with the new one you shouldnt, it says so in the instructions

Comment: @Muhammet It should be inside the `<head>` tag according to [Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080)

Comment: @tawfekov where can I find the error log? And it is from google analytics https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#home/xxxxxxxxxx (again sensored)

Comment: oh,sorry thought it would be same with normal js

Comment: "where can I find the error log?" Depends. Are you using Apache or nginx? Are you using PHP? Ruby on Rails? Sinatra.rb? Also, I agree with @tawfekov, there is no way GA could cause this. I don't think it really matters where the script is located, actually. GA doesn't impact page-loading performance that much, but I traditionally place it at the bottom myself, too.

Comment: PHP and Apache as the web server

Comment: There could be a `error_log` file inside the script's directory. Also, do you use a `.htaccess` file? I think PHP would print the error out, not cause the 500 (might depend on configuration), but a badly configured `.htaccess` could cause this.

Comment: Your code has nothing which could throw 500 error. If you use some template engine, this may be a syntax conflict. Please, tell us more about your application. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', true);` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: there is only the htdocs, no error_log, nothing inside htdocs for error either (use fasthosts) and the .htaccess file is set up fine, default wordpress .ht

Comment: I turned error reporting on, still 500 server error

Comment: Try refreshing the directory in which your script resides (after applying @BogdanBurim's snippet). There might be an error report file in there now.

Comment: Try this plugin (if you use WP) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried moving the script tag to the bottom of your content before the end of the  element?

ie:

```
<body>
  stuff here
  <ga script include>
</body>
```

The script itself is appending and loading another script tag to the top of the head. So you might be getting conflicts between GA appending and loading the new script and your other JS compiling.

Comment: Google says different here https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080

Comment: interesting https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview says to put it before the end of the body tags. So when you remove the script the 500 error goes away? what does the rest of your head tag look like? -- also have you tried starting w/ just hte ga include and then adding in your other included stuff to narrow down where the conflict is?

Comment: Yeah, 500 disappears when it's removed, the only thing I can think of is the ajax is not going somewhere or pulling something that doesnt exist. The head tag is full of php and SEO stuff and some script calls, pretty large

Comment: Are you accidentally placing the GA inside a `<?php ... ?>` block? It happened to me before.

Answer (score 7):

If your website is using the Smarty Template engine, just pasting this code into the template will cause the 500 Internal Server Error, because the template is interpreting the code improperly.

Past the code inside a

```
{literal} 
...
{/literal}
```

block and your problems will be solved!

Shout out to [Logicia.co.uk blog](http://www.logicia.co.uk/blog/2012/04/google-analytics-and-the-smarty-template-engine/comment-page-1/#comment-83997) which helped me out with this same issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wouldn't have thought of that. This saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten the 500 Error too.
In my case, it was the template engine smarty!!!

It takes this line as a smarty command because of the `{}`

```
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
```

change this to:

```
{literal}function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}{/literal}
```

maybe someone runns in this error with smarty too :-)

Answer (score -1):

*WAG (Wild-A***-Guess)*, based on your comment about lots of other SEO stuff and scripts in head...

Split the analytics code into two parts. Put the part that loads `ga.js` closer to the top of head, above any other script calls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 
    'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 
    'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Put the other part, that performs the analytics at the bottom of the head tag, or even at the bottom of the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxxx']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

If you're still having problems, see what happens if you remove the `_gaq` code altogether

- If you still get 500 errors, then the problem is with the async loading of `ga.js`. You could try switching to the older, non-async style of Google Analytics.
- If the error goes away, then the problem is with the analytics tracking pixels requests...